# Paython (Pandas) : count frequency of each cell in for two column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this in python

```
 name    id     Background Complexion      Ear Ear Accessories
Li1     3800          White      Clean  Ape Ear            None
Lio2    5700  Purple Galaxy      Clean  Ape Ear  Silver Earring
Lio4    8400          Green      Clean  Orc Ear   Spiky Earring
Noam    3000    Noir Galaxy      Clean  Ape Ear  Silver Earring
AVERSE  6100    Grey Galaxy      Clean  Ape Ear  Gender Earring
```

I want to count every cell except two first colmn 'name' and 'id' and create a table like this finally

```
name    id     Background Complexion     Ear    Ear Accessories
Li1     3800          1      5           4            1
Lio2    5700          1      5           4            2
Lio4    8400          1      5           1            1
Noam    3000          1      5           4            2
AVERSE  6100          1      5           4            1
```

and calculate a formula on this numbers (for example +3) then we have

```
name    id     Background Complexion     Ear    Ear Accessories
Li1     3800          4      8           7            4
Lio2    5700          4      8           7            5
Lio4    8400          4      8           4            4
Noam    3000          4      8           7            5
AVERSE  6100          4      8           7            4
```

and sum numbers for each row

```
name    id     Background Complexion     Ear    Ear Accessories  sum
Li1     3800          4      8           7            4           23
Lio2    5700          4      8           7            5           24 
Lio4    8400          4      8           4            4           20
Noam    3000          4      8           7            5           24
AVERSE  6100          4      8           7            4           23
```

how can do this with pandas in python
thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to loop to perform a count per column. You can use `groupy.transform('count')`. The rest are simple vectorial operations (`add`/`sum`):

```
cols = ['name', 'id']
df2 = (df[cols]
       .join(pd.DataFrame({c: df.groupby(c)[c].transform('count')
                           for c in df.drop(columns=cols).columns})
               .add(3)
               .assign(sum=lambda d: d.sum(1))
            )
      )
```

output:

```
     name    id  Background  Complexion  Ear  Ear Accessories  sum
0     Li1  3800           4           8    7                4   23
1    Lio2  5700           4           8    7                5   24
2    Lio4  8400           4           8    4                4   20
3    Noam  3000           4           8    7                5   24
4  AVERSE  6100           4           8    7                4   23
```

Comment: thank you. i got this error when use this code.```PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.```

Comment: Do you have a MultiIndex? I don't know where this comes from, but you can probably ignore the warning. If performance is critical, please edit your question to provide the real dataset as `df.head(10).to_dict()`.

Comment: dear @mozway . I add output of df.head(10).to_dict() if question

Comment: sorry . this is error i get. ```ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Comment: @Mehdi weird, you have a MultiIndex but with a single level. Run `df.columns = [x[0] for x in df.columns]` and the the above code should work fine